# How to connect PySpark to Bigquery

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery

I am trying to read a table form BigQuery using PySpark.

I have tried the following

```
table = 'my-project-id.project-dataset.test_table_spark'
df = spark.read.format('bigquery').option('table', table).load()
```

However, I am getting this error

```
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

How can I read the bigQuery table from pySpark (at the moment I'm using python2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include the jar for the [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector) with your `spark-submit`. The easiest way to do that would be using the `--jars` flag to include the publicly available and most up-to-date version of the connector:

```
spark-submit --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar my_job.py
```

Though the examples reference Cloud Dataproc, this should work when submitting to any Spark cluster.

Comment: is there a way to test it from the notebook? I'm using jupyter as web interface (or testing via SSH) and I don't know how to use the --jars flag in this case

Comment: You can try this when creating your SparkSession: `spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('my_app).config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar').getOrCreate()`

Comment: Try restarting your Jupyter notebook. If you have any pre-existing SparkSessions, this won't work. Also, make sure you're using a Python Jupyter kernel, not a PySpark Jupyter kernel, per this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Top%20words%20in%20Shakespeare%20by%20work.ipynb

Comment: The last solution you posted works and I can read from BQ using pyspark. However, it seems I can't use other packages (such as graphframes). It can't find anymore the class GraphFramePythonAPI. I suspect it is because I'm now running it from a python notebook..

Comment: You can manually add packages to the config also. Try this: `conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar'), ('spark.jars.packages', 'graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11'])` just make sure to replace graphframes with the appropriate package for your version of spark found using `pyspark.__version__` from https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes. Then, `spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('my_app').config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()`